# Как строковую переменную ( в js ) вывести между (например) тегами <h1> </h1>

Tags: javascript, html

Допустим, у меня есть html страница:`<h1 id="text"></h1>` и js код: `var text = ["text 1","text 2"]`. Как мне (по нажатию кнопки) вставить один(рандомный) элемент из массива между тегами?

Comment: не нашел подходящее решение

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
var text = ["text 1", "text 2", "text 3", "text 4"]
var text_label = $('#text');
var button = $('button');

button.click(function() {
  var random = getRandomInt(0, text.length);
  text_label.text(text[random]);
});

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="text"></h1>
<button>Magick!</button>
```

Вот полный код, и краткое пояснение.

getRandomInt - возвращает случайное целое число от min до max.

При клике на кнопку мы передаем в getRandomInt 0 и длинну массива в качестве параметров, получаем случайное значение в этом диапазоне, и вставляем результат в текстовое поле